# Among java.util.* and java.util.Scanner, performance wise which one is better?

Tags: java

java.util.* import all the class under it, while java.util.Scanner only imports Scanner class.
So, is there any difference between them in time of execution between them?

Comment: How does this relate to c, c#, php or asp.net?

Comment: The short answer is no.  Imports are used by the compiler; they don't affect run time.

Comment: It might not affect runtime execution but I think it's best practice to only import the stuff you're going to use. Be it for better readability for yourself or for people reading/analyzing your code.

Comment: Oh, absolutely, you should never use imports with `*`.  But not because of readability.  Using import with `*` can make your code break if new classes are introduced in future versions of Java.  Never, ever, use `*`.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem good point actually, didn't think of it that way :) Some (if not all) IDE's usually replace your specific imports with `*` if they are from the same `package`. Should look into disabling that function ;)

Comment: There should be dup for this one. Nobody found that yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike the `#include` thingy in C, `import`ing stuff in Java does not actually copy stuff, so performance-wise, `java.util.*` and `java.util.Scanner` are practically the same.

However, importing everything from a package can cause name conflicts. Look at how many classes there are that are called `Scanner`:

[image]

If you just so happens to import everything from both `java.util` and `sun.tools.java`. The compiler will not be able to infer which `Scanner` you are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

java.util.* will import the entire utility classes whereas java.util.Scanner will import only Scanner class. Now, it is up to you as if you want to take input from user then import only java.util.Scanner class specifically.

It is always best practice to import specific class because importing entire package may confuse you. 
Eg java has 2 Date classes in two different packages 
   1)java.util.Date
   2)java.sql.Date

When we import an entire package using '*' and if any error occurs then we don't understand because of which class this error has occurred that's why it is always best practice to import specific class according to the requirement.

Thank you.
Rupesh R. Bharuka